# No upgrade option from 14.04 to 15.04 in software center

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

So now that Ubuntu 15.04 is out, I tried to update my system. I opened the software update center and it gave a small security update from a few days ago, but no mention of a new version of Ubuntu. What am I to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

14.04 is an LTS version. By default it will only upgrade releases every two years when the next LTS comes out. In **Ubuntu Software Center** go to `Edit...Software Sources...` click the `Updates` tab, then change the drop down "Notify me of a new Ubuntu Version" from

```
For long-term support versions
```

to

```
For any new version
```